# How to prove this statement and its negation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Assuming that you're dealing with real numbers,

d ^ 2 = e ^ 2, then d = e

Why would it be true?  << corrected, it is not true! thanks to posters

What is the negation and is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not actually true: $d = 1$ and $e = -1$ certainly gives a counterexample. All we can say is that $d = \pm e$; this follows from the fact that

$$0 = d^2 - e^2 = (d - e)(d + e)$$

Now the set of real numbers under the usual operations forms an object called an [integral domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain): The most important property, other than the usual rules of arithmetic, is that it satisfies:

> If $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ab = 0$, then $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.

From this, it follows that $d - e = 0$ or $d + e = 0$, so that $d = \pm e$.

Comment: So a proof by counterexample seems sufficient here. Great response.

Comment: So the negation would simply be that d does not equal e? And I'm supposing this could be proven by d = 1, e = -1

Comment: @user3308043 The negation is just "It is not true that if $d^2 = e^2$, then $d = e$."

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $2^2 = (-2)^2$ but $2\neq -2$.